# Can "boiling wine in the oven" make it Halal?

Tags: halal-haram, food, alcohol

Does "boiling wine in the oven" make it Halal?

has this problem different answers depending on the denomination or is there consensus about it?

Comment: You would need to remove 100% of the alcohol content in the wine. Jews boil wine for a different reason but it contains alcohol after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Any type of alcohol is forbidden no matter how it is handled. Not sure if there is a difference of opinion among scholars though.

Comment: Generally, I think it is not true. Because, by processing, it will be transformed into vinegar (Halal product). Right?

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/55863/43280
This post here goes more into depth so it might be better looking at this.

Comment: Boiling wine *will* drive off the alcohol (strong drinks are made by condensing the alcohol from the resulting steam).  But it will also drive off the volatile organic compounds that give wine its prized flavour.  So as NinjaSauce says, why would you?

Answer (score 0):

Wine is haram because of its intoxicating properties. Boiling fluids gets rid of bacteria and diseases but that is not what cause wine to make you drunk. In other words, wine is haram because it makes you drunk, and boiling it still makes you drunk.

Comment: So, you are saying, boiling will not cause of removing alcohol in the wine. Right? So, if it is, it will be Halal. Right?

Comment: Yes, but without the alcohol idk why you would even drink it.