# Did Imam Maalik say it is impermissible to produce Vinegar from Wine

Tags: reference-request, alcohol, maliki

I read on an islamqa.info fatwa that this is what Imam maalik said. But a reference was not listed and I do not know where to find one, if it exists please tell me it. Thanks

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q &A site about Islam. Please consider sharing the fatwa in question instead of linking the site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is alcohol based vinegar allowed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55863/is-alcohol-based-vinegar-allowed) ... see Medi1Saif's answer as it covers the view of Imam Malik.

Comment: It just says that Maalik said so, but did he say it? I am looking for a Quote by him or a companion of his that attributed the view to Imam Maalik